# A game of plates and olives

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability

This  question  has its origin  in Morse theory ([see this paper](http://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/Morse-count.pdf)) but it can be given an entirely  elementary and amusing  formulation.

The game  of  plates and  olives starts with an empty table and ends with an empty table and it  consists of   a succession of the following elementary moves.

($P_+)$  Add an empty plate on the table.

($O_+$)  Add an olive on an existing plate.

($P_-$)   Move all the olives from a plate $p_0$ to a plate $p_1$ and then smash the plate  $p_0$. (A degenerate case of this move is when $p_0$ is an empty plate and you simply smash it.)

($O_-$) Eat one olive from one of the plates.

Note that the $P_\pm$-move  change the number of plates by $\pm 1$, while the $O_\pm$-move changes the number  of olives by $\pm 1$.

As I mentioned  early on, a game starts  with an empty table and ends  when we smash the last remaining plate  on the table, which has to be free of olives.  *The olives are indistinguishable, and so are the plates.*  The length of a game is the number of elementary   moves  it consists of, from the beginning  to the end.

During a  complete game,   the number of $P_+$-moves must equal the number of $P_-$-moves and the number of $O_+$-moves must equal the number of  $O_-$ moves. Thus, the length of a game is a positive even integer.  $\newcommand{\bZ}{\mathbb{Z}}$  For any $n\in\bZ_{\geq 0}$ we denote by $G_n$ the number  of  games of length $2n+2$.   In the paper mentioned above I showed

$$ G_n \geq (2n+1) !! $$

It is my strong belief  that this inequality is  asymptotically sharp on a logarithmic scale, i.e.,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log G_n}{\log (2n+1)!!}= 1, $$

or, in view of Stirling's formula

$$\log G_n \sim n\log n\;\;\mbox{as}\; n\to\infty.$$

This has resisted all my on and off attempts to prove it.

> **Question 1.** Is my above belief justified?

One can also randomize this game.  This means  that, at every stage during the game,  we  choose the moves available to us uniformly at random.

For example , if  during the game we reach  a situation when there are $a$ plates and $b$ olives  on the table, then the options  available to us are

One possible $P_+$ move,

$a$ possible $O_+$ moves (there are $a$ plates where we can place a new olive),

$b$ possible $O_-$ moves and

$\binom{a}{2}$ possible  $P_-$ moves.

> **Question 2.** Is the expected duration  of such a random game finite?

Thank you.

**Comment 1.**  Let me expand,   based on @michael  answer. During  a game the pair $(a,b)$ undergoes a random walk on the lattice

$$ (a,b)\in \bZ_{\geq 0}\times \bZ_{\geq 0}\setminus \big(\{0\}\times \bZ_{>0}\big),\;\;$$ with transition probabilities  described above. (The horizontal axis is th plate axis, and the vertical axis is the olive axis.) This is easily seen to be irreducible, and $(0,0)$ is a reflecting state.  A more refined version of Question 2 would be the following.

> **Question 2.1** Describe the dynamics of this  Markov chain.

Comment: Clarification question: You seem to be treating the eating of two different olives on the same plate as two distinct moves which lead to two distinct games, is that correct? (We could imagine a version of the game where the $O_-$ move is to choose some nonempty plate and reduce the number of olives on it by one. But that is not happening here: you must also pick which olive. Right?)

Comment: Yes. Every move must  change  either the number of plates by $\pm 1$ or the number of olives by $\pm 1$.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu: I don't think you understood the point of usul's question.

Comment: The olives are indistinguishable and so are the plates. What you should keep track at each stage is the the number of olives on each plate arranged in decreasing order. E,g.  a string (2,2,1,0,0)  means that we have 2 plates containing 2 olives each, 1 plate with a single olive and 1 empty plate.  Also, I've just received privately a positive answer to Question1.  The author promised  he  will soon post his answer  on MO.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu, to clarify, in your example in the response above mine, how many different $O_-$ moves are there? I can see the answer as 5, because there are 5 different olives; or 3, because there are three nonempty plates to choose from. It's additionally tricky because there are only *two* possible "states" that can result from eating an olive: (2,2,0,0,0) and (2,1,1,0,0).

Comment: There's a typo in my previous comment. I meant a string (2,2,1,0).  An $O_+$  move on such string can produce a string (3,2,1,0) or a string (2,2,2,0) or a string (2,2,1,1). An $O_-$  move can produce string (2,1,1,0) or a string (2,2,0,0).

Comment: Call it move of type $O_-$.  or of type $O_+$ There can be several possible moves of type $O_\pm$.

Comment: As explained in my earlier comment, for the string (2,2,1,0) the moves of type $O_-$ can produce only two *distinguishable*  outcomes.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu, sorry but it is still not clear to me how we are counting games and moves! How many moves of type $O_-$ are there from the string $(2,2,1,0)$? Are two games that have the same sequence of strings counted as the same game, even if the moves are different?

For example, suppose I create two plates and then add two olives to the first plate, then two to the second. Then I eat all the olives, then I smash plate 1, then 2. How many games satisfy this description? I see arguments for 4!, 6 (the ways to pick two plates twice each), or 2 (the unique string sequences you described).

Comment: To further explain why this bothers me, I feel there is a contradiction between the statements "the olives are indistinguishable" and "there are $b$ possible $O_-$ moves when there are $b$ olives". For instance, if there is a single plate with $b$ olives on it, are there $b$ different $O_-$ moves?

Comment: I think maybe you meant to say that when there are $a$ plates of which $b$ are non-empty there are $b$ moves of type $O_-$

Comment: Here is one game of length 6: 1. put a plate down, 2. put an olive on the plate, 3. put another olive on the  same plate, 4. eat an olive, 5. eat the other olive, 6. smash the  empty plate.  Here is another  game of length 8: 1. put   a plate down, 2.  put an olive on the plate, 3. put another plate down, 4.  put on olive on the new plate,  5. transfer an olive from one plate to another and smash the empty plate, 6. eat an olive,7.  eat the other olive, 8.  smash the empty plate.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu: I think you are still missing usul's point. Suppose you 1. put a plate down, 2. put an olive on that plate, and 3. put another olive on that plate. Are there now two $O^{-}$ moves available to you (because we consider eating those two olives as different moves, even though they bring you to the same state), or only one?

Comment: There two moves of the *same* type.    All you care is the *outcome*. They both have the same outcome.

Comment: Also, saying that the olives are indistinguishable implies that these two $O_-$ moves are indistinguishable because both their inputs and their outputs are indistinguishable.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu: "There two moves of the same type. All you care is the outcome." - But it seems like for purposes of defining the Markov chain in Question 2, it matters whether we weight transitions by the number of "moves" (where these two $O^{-}$ which produce the same outcome count as different moves), or just the number of possible outcomes.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu: Even for Question 1, it seems relevant whether you consider two moves (e.g. two $O^{-}$ moves) that produce the same outcome to count as different games.

Comment: For the Markov chain leave the randomness as is. It is better adapted to the original  Morse theoretic problem.  It does not mean this the only possibility. (When a randomizer  decides to eat an olive and sees  5  on the table  he has 5 choices in front of him.) The Markov chain involves a weighted count of games, different from  Question 1. All I care is the  average length under those precise   randomness  conditions.

Comment: @Sam Hopkins To make it very clear: two  $O_-$ moves with indistinguishable inputs  and indistinguishable outputs  are to be considered indistinguishable.

Comment: Can we just say plates are olives and simplify the description to talk about piles of olives? $P_-$ becomes merge two piles and eat an olive from the merger.

Comment: @DanPiponi No, for reasons having to do with the Morse theoretic nature of the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer to Question 1 is that yes, the belief is justified. By Stirling's approximation, $(2n+1)!!=n^n(2/e)^{n(1+o(1))}$ or $\log (2n+1)!! = n \log n +n(2/e)(1+o(1))$, so for an affirmative answer to Question 1 it is enough to get an upper bound on $G_n$ of the form $G_n \leq n^nC^n$ for some constant $C$.

Here's a sketch of such an upper bound. A game of length $2n$ involves $n$ "$+$'' moves (either $P_+$ or $O_+$) and $n$ "$-$'' moves, so the profile of a game, at the high level of where $+$ moves and $-$ moves are made, can be specified at a cost of $\binom{2n}{n}$ (but a bound of $4^n$ is fine here, too).

Now consider a game in which there are exactly $t$ $O_+$ moves. There are at most $\binom{n}{t}$ options for the location of these moves, and at most $\binom{n}{t}$ options for the location of the corresponding $O_-$ moves.

We now have to consider how many options there are at each $P_+$, $P_-$, $O_+$ and $O_-$ move. That's easy for the $P_+$ moves --- these involve no choice.

For the other moves: given a configuration ${\mathcal C}$ of plates and olives, let $o({\mathcal C})$ be the total number of olives, and let $p({\mathcal C})$ be the size of $\{k:\mbox{in ${\mathcal C}$ there is a plate with $k$ olives}\}$. Then we have (basically) $p({\mathcal C}) \leq \sqrt{2o({\mathcal C})}$, because to have $p({\mathcal C})$ any larger we would need more than $0+1+\cdots + \sqrt{2o({\mathcal C})} \approx o({\mathcal C})$ olives.

We can now bound the number of options at $P_-$ moves by $(\sqrt{2t})^2$ (we have to choose a plate to remove, cost at most $\sqrt{2t}$, the largest possible value of $o({\mathcal C})$ when there are $t$ $O_+$ moves, and then choose a plate on which to deposit the olives from the removed plate, again cost at most $\sqrt{2t}$). So the maximum contribution from $P_-$ moves is $(2t)^{n-t}$. Here and in the next paragraph we are crucially using that all plates with the same numbers of olives on them are indistinguishable.

At the $\ell$th $O_+$ move, there are at most $\sqrt{2\ell}$ options (because there are at most $\ell$ olives on the table at that time), and at the $(t-\ell)$th $O_-$ move there are again at most $\sqrt{2\ell}$ options (with only $\ell$ $O_-$ moves remaining, there are again at most $\ell$ olives on the table at that time). The maximum contribution from $O_+$ and $O_-$ moves is then at most
$$
\left(\prod_{\ell \leq t} \sqrt{2\ell}\right)^2 \approx 2^t t! \approx 2^t\left(\frac{t}{e}\right)^t.
$$

Putting it all together we get an upper bound on $G_n$ of the form
$$
\sum_{t \leq n} 4^n\binom{n}{t}^2 2^t \left(\frac{t}{e}\right)^t (2t)^{n-t} = 8^n\sum_{t \leq n} \binom{n}{t}^2 \frac{t^n}{e^t}.
$$

Parameterizing $t=\alpha n$ the summand above is (basically) 
$$
n^n \exp_2\left\{n(2H(\alpha) +\log_2 \alpha -\alpha\log_2 e)\right\}
$$ 
where $H(x)$ is the binary entropy function. So we have an upper bound of
$$
G_n \leq n^n C^n
$$
where 
$$
C=8 \times \exp_2\left\{\max_{\alpha \in (0,1)} (2H(\alpha) +\log_2 \alpha -\alpha\log_2 e)\right\}.
$$

With Teena Carroll at Emory & Henry we have been working to optimize this argument (there's lots of room for improvement), and we can currently get $C$ down to about 1.87, off by a multiplicative factor of about 2.5 from the $(2/e)$ appearing in the lower bound.

Comment: I have edited. I bounded $\binom{n}{\alpha n}^2$ by $2^{nH(\alpha)}$, but then when I pulled the factor of $n$ from this and the two other terms outside the parentheses, I forgot to delete the $n$ inside.

Comment: Hats  off to   you David and Teena.

Comment: It looks like this has been written up here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.10670

Answer (score 8):

As to the expected duration, if you look at the total number of plates plus olives there are a+1 moves which increase it and ${ a \choose  2 } + b$ which decrease it, therefore it increases with probability at least $\frac {a + 1} {{a \choose  2 } + b + a + 1}$.  As long as a + b is at least 5 this number is always small, much less than .5 (full disclosure: haven't proven that, just plotted a few cases).  This guarantees that you will return to N < 5 at least like a random walk with negative drift, which occurs in finite expected time.It is standard to show that since you have a positive probability of ending within 5 steps from there you will soon do it, also within finite expected time.

Comment: Should "at least" be "at most"? I'm having a hard time parsing this answer...

Comment: Yes, sorry.  I had originally intended to  write the probability of decrease.  These arguments are a mess to write down, but I hope the basic idea of comparing it to a random walk with negative drift is clear.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Michael’s answer isn’t quite right. If we just consider a 1-dimensional random walk that tracks the olives(as long as we have at least one), this is a random walk with a slight positive bias(we can add an olive to any plate that we can remove an olive from, and we can add an olive to empty plates as well.), so this random walk has infinite expected time before it returns to zero olives. If we never get down to zero olives, we never get an empty table.

The issue with Michael’s answer is that it doesn’t consider what is happening when there is only a single plate.